# Entity Framework the use of reference

Tags: entity-framework

I use

```
p.AuthorsReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("PetitionsContainer.Authors", "Id", authorId);
```

but I get entities in `PetitionsContainer.Questions` participate in the `QuestionAuthor` relationship.

`0 related 'Author' were found. 1 'Author' is expected.`

Now, the `Author` with the Id `authorId` is already in the database.

It is true that each question must have 1 author.

Though, can't I use  `AuthorsReference` instead of something like `p.Authors.Add(new Author())`?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up the reference you must also fill the author. You can try using this:

```
// Attach a dummy author to the context so that context believes that you
// loaded the author from the database
Author a = new Author { Id = authorId };
context.Authors.Attach(a);
// Now assign existing author to the question
question.Author = a;
```